# Keep background image full height while cropping only sides to keep ratio

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a mobile page with full screen background image.

I have one image for portrait and one for landscape. My mission is to keep image height full screen while cropping the sides to fit screen and keep aspect ratio.

I tried this css tricks [post](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) :

```
  html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

While working great (as I needed) on portrait, it doesn't meet my needs on landscape:
It keeps the image full screen width and crops it from the top and bottom (My requirement from the designers is keep full screen height and crop the sides).
There are a lot of examples on the internet for keeping image's ratio etc. (for [example](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios) ), but I could find a solution for my situation...

Thanks!
Yaniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This managed to work for me, this is based on the image being a large enough size to cover large screen sizes...

```
 html { 
  background: url(http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1338.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  }
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dX22r/)

Comment: It works, tnx! The only thing missing is the: background-size: cover; in order to make it work.